# OpenPDF columnText.go creating corrupt document

Tags: itext, openpdf

I keep getting an error of

[image: Error]

when I try writing to the PDF with columnText. `setSimpleColumn()` used to work fine, but now this code is throwing the error, also when I tried using a `setColumns()` it also is throwing an error. I can't think of what is causing the error. Was I supposed to close the columnText somehow?

The immediately related code is:

```
fun testBox(content: List, font: List, page: Int, leftLimit: Float, rightLimit: Float, topLimit: Float, bottomLimit: Float){
val columnText = ColumnText(setCanvas("$filepath$name.pdf",page))
columnText.alignment = ALIGN_JUSTIFIED
columnText.runDirection = RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
columnText.setSimpleColumn(leftLimit, bottomLimit, rightLimit, getRectangle("LETTER").top-topLimit)
var i = 0

while (i < content.size) {
    columnText.addText(Chunk(content[i], font[i]))
    columnText.go()
    i++
}
}
```

I'll show more code if needed, but I don't think the rest of it is related to the issue.

I'm really stumped, and I can't find much info on this issue.

This is the resulting file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/135EhLyiyDj6iAexUJ0upRdG6eXHYXVdw/view?usp=sharing

EDIT:
I forgot that I made the function `setCanvas` in order to save a bunch of code, here is the function:

```
fun setCanvas(file: String, page: Int): PdfContentByte? {
    val reader = PdfReader(file)
    val stamper = PdfStamper(reader, FileOutputStream(File(file)))
    if(reader.numberOfPages < page){ stamper.insertPage(reader.numberOfPages + (page-reader.numberOfPages), reader.getPageSize(1) ?: getRectangle("LETTER")); if (page - reader.numberOfPages != 1){throw Error("EMPTY PAGE!")}}
    return stamper.getOverContent(page)
}
```

EDIT 2: [combined two functions]

```
    testBox(listOf(content1,content2,content3), listOf(font,fontBold,font), 1, document.left(), document.right(), document.bottom(),document.top())


fun testBox(content: List<String>, font: List<Font>, page: Int, leftLimit: Float, rightLimit: Float, topLimit: Float, bottomLimit: Float){
    val reader = PdfReader("$filepath$name.pdf")
    val stamper = PdfStamper(reader, FileOutputStream(File("$filepath$name - edit.pdf")))
    if(reader.numberOfPages < page){ stamper.insertPage(reader.numberOfPages + (page-reader.numberOfPages), reader.getPageSize(1) ?: getRectangle("LETTER")); if (page - reader.numberOfPages > 0){throw Error("EMPTY PAGE!")}}
    val columnText = ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(page))

    columnText.alignment = ALIGN_JUSTIFIED
    columnText.runDirection = RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
    columnText.setSimpleColumn(leftLimit, bottomLimit, getRectangle("LETTER").right - rightLimit, getRectangle("LETTER").top- topLimit)
    var i = 0
    while (i<content.size) {
        columnText.addText(Chunk(content[i], font[i]))
        columnText.go()
        i++
    }
}
```

link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ybvDVSxKOJdbnA2fSRjEmxlDszIktWTL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You say that *the code is throwing an error*. Do you mean an exception occurs while you run your code? Or do you mean that later a viewer shows the error dialog when showing the output of your code?

Comment: The code runs fine. When I try to open the resulting PDF this pops up. Which makes it really hard to debug.

Comment: please share an example result PDF of your code.

Comment: I don’t understand. I can’t open the PDF. When I try, this error pops up.

Comment: please make an example result PDF of your code available for download, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Upload the created file?

Comment: Yes, e.g. to google drive or drop box as a public share, and post the URL here.

Comment: @mkl I had uploaded the file, and added the link into the question.

Comment: Your shared file is exactly 0 byte long. So no wonder. Considering your method `setCanvas`, though: That cannot work properly, you have to keep the `stamper` from premature finalization and eventually, after all changes have been applied, you have to explicitly close it.

Comment: Another issue, input and output of a stamping must differ.

Comment: Ok. I changed my code. But even with the different name, it’s still not working. Maybe because of the “premature finalization” and “closing” you mentioned. But I haven’t seen anything talking about that. Could you please explain what that “premature finalization” is and how to close properly?

Comment: @mkl I’ve tried moving the setCanvas function back into the bigger function. I think it now creates 8mg files, but I still can’t open them.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the current state of your code and, if possible, to include a link to a result generated by it.

Comment: @mkl I put the new code in the question. and I guess I was looking at an old file; this still produces a 0kb file. (The empty - 1 blank page - pdf that the code creates in order for this to reference is 794 bytes)

Comment: First of all add a `stamper.close()` after the `while` loop.

Comment: @mkl YAY! It stopped producing a corrupt file! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I wrapped up the discussion in the comments here in an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your original code:

- You use the same source and target file for stamping.
- You don't keep a reference to the `PdfStamper` to close it *after* manipulating the PDF.

The first problem causes the file to be truncated *before* it is completely read. This you fixed in your edit.

The second may cause your output PDF to not become finished, missing a necessary trailer.

After also fixing the second problem your code finally *stopped producing a corrupt file*.